# AutoQuery add logic to select

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using AutoQuery feature and say I have something like this:

```
public class Rockstar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}    

public class QueryCustomRockstars : QueryBase<Rockstar, CustomRockstar> {}

public class CustomRockstar
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string FullName { 
        get {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all good until I try to sort on the FullName field as it's not part of the actual SQL query. So what I need is to be able to generate the query to do something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) As FullName
```

I looked through the docs and I couldn't find anything to do with customising the select portion of the query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only be possible using [Raw SQL Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#raw-sql-filters), but then you would need to take over the entire SELECT expression.

Ordering by multiple columns has similar behavior to ordering by FullName:

```
?OrderBy=FirstName,LastName
```

Another option is to create a RDBMS View and change AutoQuery to query that instead.

Comment: In this case I could use multiple order by columns, but in most cases where I need to use COALESCE, more complex CASE WHEN statements or subqueries this wouldn't so simple. Good to know that it's possible with Raw SQL, albeit not as nice. 

Do you have any plans to add a Query modifier for the returned object models so that the select statement can be modified per attribute?

Comment: @vonec AutoQuery goal is to provide simple, intuitive and RDBMS-agnostic auto querying, whilst you have some control with [extensibility options in AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#extensibility-with-queryfilters), if you need anything more complicated it's best to go with a Custom Service.